# unencrypted db not being created by net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, encryption, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

In my android app, I need to give user an option to create an encrypted or non-encrypted database; The database will be saved in device sdcard.

For the non-encrypted db I'm using :-

db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, "", null);

but when I open the db through command line,it gives error: file is encrypted or is not a database.
So the above code line always creates encrypted database.

My code is below:

```
if(db == null){
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context);
        String encryptStr = "";

        if(new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME).exists()){
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, encryptStr, null);
        }else{

            db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, encryptStr,          null);
            executeSchema(context);
        }

        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        db = null;
        AlertHelper.logError(e);
    }
}
```

Any way to create non-encrypted database using sqlcipher in android?.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer. Using empty string string as password does creates non-encrypted db. My problem was that I was using command line to check db; It does not supports sqlcipher.database so it always returned db as encrypted.

I pulled my db from device using 'pull' button in eclpise and then opened it in Lita(software for viewing db). The db with empty key opens up but with non-empty key it tells that db is encrypted and thus can't be opened.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have used the right method? I couldn't find the

db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, "", null);

method,

I just see these methods:

SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, factory)

SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, factory)

SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, factory, flags)

Comment: I'm importing net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;                            and using SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase (String path, String password, CursorFactory factory)